# Subdividing regular pentagon into six congruent pieces

Tags: geometry, puzzle

It is easy to divide a 2-gon into 3 congruent line segments.
It is also easy to divide a triangle into 4 smaller triangles that are congruent. One of Martin Gardner's favorite problems is to show that one can divide a square (regular 4-gon) into five congruent and connected pieces.

The natural question is then: can one subdivide a regular pentagon into six congruent and preferably connected pieces?

Comment: There is something called the Baumann's $6$ divided pentagon. It divides the pentagon into $6$ pentagons, all connected. You can look at this image: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwj75ZG06fnPAhWJuo8KHas-CuAQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Frangevoting.org%2FPuzzGerryOpt.html&psig=AFQjCNGrvAj8Ck0xjPh-HmcPAT5geXgxrQ&ust=1477617801987254 , somewhere in the middle of the page you will see a diagram

Comment: That is quite interesting, but the pieces are not congruent. Five of the pieces are, but the center piece is different.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: by *congruent* you mean isometric or just with the same area?

Comment: Are you sure that the lines cannot be adjusted, to make pieces with the same area? Because if it is congruence with respect to shape, then the answer is wrong, of course.

Comment: Well, in that case, all pieces would be regular pentagons, and what we would have is is nothing but a side of a dodecahedron, which is not flat.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253494/subdivision-of-pentagon-into-six-congruent-pieces